# chef undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass with attributes

Tags: chef-infra

I working on chef which i needs to call attribute value from `attributes/default.rb` file to `recipe/default.rb` file.
I am invoked attribute values in recipe which throws an error

> undefined method [] for nil:NilClass`

Can someone help me on this.

```
# attribute/default.rb
default['app']['dir'] =  "/opt/app/"

# recipe/default.rb
ruby_block 'print_name' do
  block do
    puts "My app dir #{ node['app']['dir'] } "
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you copy&paste this? The code looks correct in terms of that you should be able to access this attribute. The failure indicates that `node['app']` is `nil` instead of a Hash.

Comment: i ran that code in the recipe file. but still i am facing nil class error.

What is the solution for that. How to resolve it?

Comment: Can you share the code on Github or similar?

Comment: Ah.. what's the name of the attributes directory? Is it really `attribute/` as you write, or `attributes/`, as it is expected? Mind the trailing `s`!

Comment: You need the plural for both `attributes/` and `recipes/`.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the missing `s` in `recipe/`- but then.. how should his recipe be executed at all? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing like below in place of

**puts "My app dir #{ node['app']['dir'] } "**

write

**puts "My app dir #{ node.default['app']['dir'] } "**

default['app']['dir'] =  "/opt/app/" #This is used in attributes/default.rb

This is priority.
node.overwrite > node.normal > node.default